# Data from tmdb API failed to fetch after deployment using vercel but works perfectly on development

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I built a mini project using Next.js. I used TMdb movie API after I signup and got the API key. After I was done building the project, everything was working fine, the data from the API is fetched perfectly. After deploying on vercel, the data which include the movie image, the title, etc., which I make a movie card out of these are not showing but the static page such as about page and other components such as header and search are all deployed.

I was expecting the those movie cards to show after deployment.